# Need time series visualization software with zoom

Tags: time-series, software

I am responsible for providing time series data to my co-workers monthly as line charts. The plots consist of two series: the actual data and a moving-average smoothed line.

I am currently doing this with Excel charts exported to PDF and distributed by email. This is an OK approach except that we now have over 10 years of monthly data and the charts - containing all 10+ years - are becoming useless for analyzing patterns in recent subsets of the series.

I'm looking for a solution where I can present my co-workers something similar to the [charts used in Google Finance](https://www.google.com/finance?chdnp=1&chdd=1&chds=1&chdv=1&chvs=maximized&chdeh=0&chfdeh=0&chdet=1433793600000&chddm=25342&chls=IntervalBasedLine&q=NASDAQ:GOOG&ntsp=0&ei=307bVbnAHNOw2AbG2ImgDA). Those charts allow the user to zoom in to see series subsets in greater detail.

I'm willing to pay for a solution, but I am on a small-business budget rather than an enterprise budget.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

For the absolutely rock bottom price of **free**, you can use the programming language `R` to create and share completely interactive time-series charts. Here are three great packages to look into using.

[Plot.ly](https://plot.ly/) is a start-up from Montreal offering easy to use software interactive graphic construction.  You can ever copy paste your data from excel into the plot.ly web interface and you're good to go.  If you ever need to automate things, look into the [plotly](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly) package released by [ROpenSci](https://ropensci.org/). You can also convert [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/) images to plot.ly plots using the `?ggplotly` function. I would start by looking in to this, as it is super useful and easy.

You might also want to look into [htmlWidgets](http://htmlwidgets.org/), a port of the popular javascript library D3 into R.  Look into the [dygraphs](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_dygraphs.html) package. Super easy to use and does a great job.

You can also use the `googleVis` package to have an API to the google-charts interface.

There are many more, but I'll stop there.  All of these plots can be made and shared in RStudio, the foremost IDE for `R`. These can also be put online through the use of `RPubs` or `shiny`, both ways of instantly sharing `R` presentations.

For more information, see my tutorial [here](https://ccole.shinyapps.io/PTP_presentation) which I'm actually giving in 20 minutes. There's a wonderful support community for `R` over at stack overflow, and the online community is more than welcoming.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I quickly answered my own question. If I use Google Sheets instead of Excel and then share the sheet, that chart type is supplied free and without programming.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into [shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) if you want more visual power.